# GeoServer REST API Issue: PUT HTTP Method

Tags: geoserver, rest, api

I've the function below which creates or replaces an existing layer group:

```
public bool AddToLayerGroup(string layerGroupName, string layerName)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrive the layer group
                string cLayerGroup = GetLayerGroup(layerGroupName);
                // Add the new layer as a new layer node among the retrieved layer nodes
                XmlDocument newLayerGrpXml = AddLayerNodeToLayerGroupXml(layerName, cLayerGroup);
                // Convert the newly created layer group xml to string
                string newLayerGrpString = ConvertXmlToString(newLayerGrpXml);
                newLayerGrpString = newLayerGrpString.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>", "");

                // Delete the existing layer group
                //DeleteLayerGroup(layerGroupName);

                // Now, do ur thing here
                string gUrl = GEOSERVER_HOST + "/rest/layergroups/" + layerGroupName + ".xml";
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(gUrl);

                request.ContentType = "application/xml";
                request.Method = "PUT";
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(GEOSERVER_USER, GEOSERVER_PASSWD);

                byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(newLayerGrpString);
                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                requestStream.Close();

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This executes successfully. Tomcat logs also indicates successful execution of the PUT method. However, I can't see the created layer group using GeoServer web UI. Is there anything else I need to do after executing the above code? Trying to create another layer group with the same name fails with the error `layer group already exists`; a further proof that the layer group was created. But, why can't I see it using the GeoServer web UI. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing every step, I found that there was a slight problem with my XML. When inserting a new layer, `<layer name="layer_name" />` is not acceptable to GeoServer, but it doesn't complain about it. It has to be `<layer><name>layer_name</name></layer>`. A C# method for constructing this XML is shown below. This now works fine:

```
private XmlDocument AddLayerNodeToLayerGroupXml(string layerName, string layerGroupString)
        {

            try
            {
                XmlDocument layerGrpXml = new XmlDocument();
                layerGrpXml.Load(new StringReader(layerGroupString));

                XmlNode layerNode = layerGrpXml.SelectSingleNode("layerGroup/layers");
                XmlNode newLayerNode = layerGrpXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "layer", null);

                XmlNode newLayerNameNode = layerGrpXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "name", null);
                newLayerNameNode.InnerText = layerName;
                newLayerNode.AppendChild(newLayerNameNode);

                layerNode.AppendChild(newLayerNode);

                XmlNode styleNode = layerGrpXml.SelectSingleNode("layerGroup/styles");
                XmlNode newLayerStyleNode = layerGrpXml.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "style", null);
                styleNode.AppendChild(newLayerStyleNode);

                layerGrpXml.Save("layerGroup.xml");

                Console.WriteLine(layerGrpXml);
                return layerGrpXml;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

In the question above, this method is called at this line `XmlDocument newLayerGrpXml = AddLayerNodeToLayerGroupXml(layerName, cLayerGroup);`.